# How can i install a third party python library (for example Pandas) in QGIS on linux?

Tags: python, qgis

I'm building a QGIS plugin, which depends on pandas and Geopandas, i am working on a Linux Xubuntu environment. How can i install these python libraries on the QGIS?

I read, OSgeo4w can be used to install third party libraries for Window OS, how can i do thesame for Linux Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 0):

After googling around, i realized that QGIS uses a standard python installation on linux, [see here (from the 2nd Answer)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/installing-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows). That is, the installed QGIS3 *(i am using QGIS3.14.16)* uses the default python3 om my Ubuntu system. So it was straight forward to install python libraries. For example by typing

- python3 -m pip install pandas
- python3 -m pip install geopandas

However, after installing geopandas QGIS crashed. After reading up some comments on similar issues [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35281#issuecomment-619130477), i was able to resolve this by downgrading the installed geopandas to geopandas==0.7.0, and shapely from 1.7.0 to shapely==1.6.0 as suggested.

**Another way to install third party library directly on QGIS** [From this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269764/how-to-install-python-library-openpyxl-in-qgis-2-18-16)

- Open a python QGIS console and type
- import pip
- pip.main(['install', 'pandas'])

These methods worked well on my Qgis3.14.16 version

Comment: import pip gives on qgis 3.22 on ubuntu an error message:
">>> import pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 982, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 925, in _find_spec
  ...

Answer (score 0):

The following workarounds do work for Mac. Hopefully they might work for linux as well

Solution 1 (via terminal):

1. open terminal and type "sudo -H /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pip3 install package_name"
2. open QGIS's python console and type "import package_name" to verify

note that "QGIS-LTR.app" can be different based on what you have installed on your system

Solution 2 (via python script):

```
try:
    import package_name
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print('Module package_name not found. Installing from PyPi')
    from pip._internal import main as pip
    pip(['install', 'package_name'])
    import package_name
    print(package_name.__version__)
```

Comment: I was trying this on my Mac Air M1 Ventura 13.5.1 OS and my QGIS got shut unexpectedly.

Comment: Can you explain what you’ve tried.